# Can not access to a protected property, but shown in page source

Tags: php, count

I have a variable in php. I `print_r` my variable (JFeed):

```
JFeed Object (
   [entries:protected] => Array
    (

        [0] => JFeedEntry Object
            (
             ...
            )

        [1] => JFeedEntry Object
            (
             ...
            )
    )
)
```

I want to count `entries` and get 2 using the following code:

`count($feed->entries); ?>`

But `entries` is a protected property. It doesn't work.

Any idea?

(Also when I print `$feed->entries` it doesn't print anything)

Comment: Exactly that is the sense of protected properties - the access limitation to the class itself and derived classes. Write an own derived class. There may be methods handling external access.

Comment: I am using `joomla` and I don't want to change joomla core. (because if I update joomla all of them will be deleted) and joomla is a very complicated.

Comment: [joomla API documentation](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JFeed.html) There are some public methods, even magic `__get` and `__set`. Thus you can access virtual properties directly.

Comment: Looking at the API, the `JFeed` class can be treated as an array. So `count($feed)` should return the number of items in `$entries`, and you should be able to just iterate through them by doing `foreach ($feed as $entry)`